# BME280 function without library, but getting negative numbers

Tags: c, arduino

so i was working with the bme280 and tried to make a function that reads the temperature without using the library. but for some reason it is giving me - numbers. does someone know why that is the case?

```
 long BME280_ReadTemperature()
{
    long temperature = 0;
    Wire.beginTransmission(BME280_ADDR);
    Wire.write(BME280_TEMP_REG);
    Wire.endTransmission();

    //request 3 bits so that it can read 3 registers
    Wire.requestFrom(BME280_ADDR, 3);

    //These three are being read as shown in the powerpoint slides
    uint8_t reading1 = Wire.read();
    uint8_t reading2 = Wire.read();
    int reading3 = Wire.read();

    temperature |= (reading1 << 8);
    temperature |= (reading2 << 4);
    temperature |= reading3;

    return temperature;
}
```

Comment: What size is `int`? What happens if you change `(reading1 << 8)` to `(long) reading1 << 8`?

Comment: when i replace it to (long) it gives me a positive number 3768, i am not sure if it is correct but at least it is not negative anymore.

Comment: The combination of 8-bit and 4-bit shift looks suspicious. Doesn't two of the three registers contain 8-bit values?

Comment: should it be two times << 8 and one time << 4?

Comment: My guess is they should be `(long)reading1 << 12` and `reading2 << 4`

Comment: just a question, why would it need to be << 12 and << 4? i am still a bit new to bits

Comment: The "temp" register of BMA150 contains bits `[3:0]` in 0xFC, `[11:4]` in 0xFB, and `[19:12]` in 0xFA. 12 and 4 are to match that layout. Ah, also I found that the `[3:0]` part is stored in bits `[7:4]` in that address, so `reading3` should be `reading3 >> 4`.

Comment: is it bad that i didn't quite understand that?

Comment: It's not so easy to program this sensor. Read point 4.2.3 of the datasheet: you have to read first all the parameters and write the compensation formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`int` in Arduino environment](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/int/) is 16-bit long. It is used for calculations of values with the size of `int` or below, but it is not sufficient to deal with 20-bit temperature value of BME280. You should use [`long`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/long/), which is 32-bit long, instead.

Also the shifting amounts looks wrong. According to 5.4.8 of the datasheet of [BME280](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/products/environmental-sensors/humidity-sensors-bme280/), The bits `[3:0]` are stored in the high half of 0xFC, bits `[11:4]` are stored in 0xFB and bits `[19:12]` are stored in 0xFA. The shift amount should match these.

In conclusion, the lines

```
    temperature |= (reading1 << 8);
    temperature |= (reading2 << 4);
    temperature |= reading3;
```

should be:

```
    temperature |= ((long)reading1 << 12);
    temperature |= (reading2 << 4);
    temperature |= (reading3 >> 4);
```

Comment: how do you know that [3:0] is 12 bits?

Comment: I don't know such wrong thing. [3:0] is 4 bits.

Comment: sorry my fault, but how do you found out that [3:0] is 4 bits? i don't understand that from reading the datasheet (i have it open)

Comment: There are 4 bits between bit 3 and bit 0, inclusive. (bit 3, bit 2, bit 1, and bit 0)

Comment: and how do you know that for [11:4] and [19:12]?

Comment: Just count bits like this. Another way is doing simple calculation: `11 - 4 + 1 = 8` and `19 - 12 + 1 = 8`.

Comment: sorry for my questions. but i don't understand how you get 12 and 4 from them.

Comment: Just see the bit number of the lowest bits.

Comment: i really don't understand that part, also looked at the datasheet.

Comment: @JessyGazar: Your `Wire.read` calls put the contents of bytes from addresses 0xFA, 0xFB, and 0xFC in `reading1`, `reading2`, and `reading3`, respectively. The eight bits that are in bits 7 to 0 of `reading1` belong in bits 19 to 12 of the temperature. To get them there, you shift them left 12 bits. The eight bits that are in bits 7 to 0 of `reading2` belong in bits 11 to 4 of the temperature. To get them there, you shift them left 4 bits. `reading3` has only four useful bits, in bits 7 to 4, and they belong in bits 3 to 0 of the temperature. To get them there, you shift them right 4 bits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Are you sure the useful bits of `reading3` are bits 3 to 0? Did you read the datasheet?

Comment: @JessyGazar: When shifting `reading1`, you cannot shift it by itself. As a `uint8_t`, `reading1` is narrower than an `int`. So, by C rules, it is automatically promoted to an `int`. But, in your C implementation, `int` is only 16 bits. When you shift the eight-bit `reading1` left 12 bits, you need 20 bits to avoid overflow. So you must convert `reading1` to `long` or `unsigned long` before the shift.